# PHPUnit's whitelist and blacklist seem to be ignored

Tags: php, phpunit, whitelist

I am setting up PHPUnit on a project which is structured the following way :

```
- build
- src
    - service # PHP source code files here
- tests
    - php
        - unit # PHP unit tests here
            - bootstrap.php # PHP unit tests here
            - services
                - MyTest.php
                - ...
- vendor
```

I created the following PHPUnit configuration file, which is located at the root of the project :

```
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.4/phpunit.xsd"
    bootstrap="tests/php/unit/bootstrap.php"
    verbose="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="services">
            <directory>tests/php/unit/services</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src/service</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="build/php/coverage"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/php/coverage.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="build/php/test-results.xml"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

I want to use a whitelist in order PHPUnit not to test out-of-project PHP files, such as those in the `vendor` directory... But looking at the code coverage report, it seems that the whitelist is not taken into account :

[image: Code coverage]

As seen on the capture the `tests` and `vendor` are written to be 0% covered, although they are not supposed to be analyzed as they don't belong to the whitelist. The '2% files' of the `src` directory corresponds to the only test that I have written, so the code coverage seems to be correct for this one.

How can I make the `src/service` really be the only directory to be analyzed to calculate the code coverage ?

I use PHP 5.4.3 and PHPUnit 4.4.5.

Comment: Having the files in `vendor` reported as `0%` means they are ignored. Does the IDE reports any of them as having more than `0%` lines covered? I guess not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved. The fact that I don't use the processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist parameter implies that except if I explicitly put directories in the whitelist they won't be coverage-analyzed. So in my case a blacklist seems to be useless since only items in the whitelist are taken into account ; and if I want to exclude subdirectories of this whitelist I can use the  tag.